# (VB.NET) Deseo abrir un segundo formulario en la misma posición respecto a un primer formulario

Tags: vb.net, formularios

Lo que trato de hacer es que cuando mueva el segundo formulario, el primero siempre se abra en la misma posición respecto al formulario padre.

En la imagen se aprecia mejor lo que deseo: El recuadro rojo viene a ser la pantalla.

- Obsérvese que el primer formulario (cuadro negro más grande) está arriba de la pantalla y luego lo muevo a la parte de abajo.
- Obsérvese que el segundo formulario está en la parte inferior derecha del primer formulario y cuando muevo el primer formulario y vuelvo a abrir el segundo formulario este siempre aparece en la misma posición respecto del primero.

**¿Cómo hago para sincronizar esa posición?**
En otras palabras no importa a qué parte de la pantalla mueva el primer formulario, cuando abra el segundo formulario siempre debe quedar en la misma posición en que quedó respecto al primero.

Debe funcionar tanto si muevo el primer formulario hacia arriba o hacia abajo, hacia la izquierda o hacia la derecha de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y como abris el segundo formulario? esto es winforms? wpf? o que? vb.net es el lenguaje de programacion, pero nos falta el entorno grafico ;)

Comment: Sorry, se me pasó ese detalle. Se trata de una aplicación winforms. El segundo formulario lo abro como un cuadro de diálogo Form2.Showdialog por ejemplo al presionar un botón ubicado en el primer formulario. O sea, el primer formulario solo se puede mover cuando el segundo formulario está cerrado.

Comment: ok.. lo abris como un model.. o sea, no es hijo del nadie... solo esta sobre.. podrias darle la posicion que queres...

Comment: Estrictamente no uso la propiedad owner, pero al abrirlo desde el botón necesariamente digamos que la jerarquía es Form1 y Form2, la única forma de mover Form1 es cerrando Form2 primero. Tu respuesta no ayuda mucho, por no decir nada con lo que solicito.

Comment: mi respuesta es la respuesta que necesitas. Para empezar, no es una respuesta, es un comentario porque a tu pregunta le falta informacion. Segundo, aunque no lo creas, te estaba ayudando un monton, No hay jerarquia, estas abriendo un modal, lo que implica que tu sistema se queda con ese form, y hasta tanto no este cerrado, no te permite abrir ni interactuar con otro. (abrilo con show y vas ver la diferencia). ahora, ya que no te estoy ayudando, voy a dejar de hacerlo.. que tengas suerte en tu busqueda!

Comment: Pucha mare te vas por detalles irrelevantes. Basta con mirar la imagen para entender lo que solicito. Sí,, se trata de un formulario modal. Es un cuadro de diálogo. Nunca dije lo contrario. Simplemente trato de sincronizar su ubicación respecto al primero. No es tan sencillo como parece sino no estuviera pidiendo ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo me pregunto y yo me respondo .

Finalmente conseguí que se sincronicen. Aquí la respuesta para el que lo necesite:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "solo esta sobre.. podrias darle la posicion que queres... ", pero no... no te respondi... deberias aprender a ser mas cortes.. Igual, autoresponderse esta muy bien visto, y dentro de 48 hs podras aceptar tu propia respuesta. hace el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio.. bienvenido...